# asp.net mvc 2 render view to string, instead of partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have this function:

```
public static string RenderViewToString(string controlName, object viewData) {
    ViewDataDictionary vd = new ViewDataDictionary(viewData);
    ViewPage vp = new ViewPage { ViewData = vd };
    Control control = vp.LoadControl(controlName);

    vp.Controls.Add(control);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            vp.RenderControl(tw);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
```

}

And I call it like this:

```
string body = StringHelpers.RenderViewToString("~/Areas/Public/Views/Shared/RegistrationEmail.ascx", new RegistrationEmailViewModel { User = user });
```

And it returns a html-table with the user-info.

But I was wondering if there is a way to edit this to I can can return a View as string? so I can add masterpage, so it'll be easier to design all potential mails going out?

Thanks in advance
/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out MVCContrib's email template system for sending emails.

http://codevanced.net/post/Sending-HTML-emails-with-ASPNET-MVC2-and-MVCContrib.aspx

Update:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string) and/or [this article](http://www.marklio.com/marklio/PermaLink,guid,90f5b539-3f7f-4309-a70a-fe98fdbc7347.aspx) might help if you don't want to include Mvccontrib. Although I use Mvccontrib every day, it's harmless.

Comment: Is there some easy way of modifying my code instead of adding mvccontrib? something.renderview?